# How do I combine CSV Files?

Tags: python, csv

I'm trying to combine 12 CSV files together using the below code, but keep getting the error "FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/RW/Desktop/London_Crime_Data'"

```
csv_filepath = '/Users/RW/Desktop/London_Crime_Data'
os.chdir(csv_filepath)
all_filenames = [i for i in glob.glob('*.{}'.format(extension))]
combined_csv = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f) for f in all_filenames ])
#export to csv
combined_csv.to_csv("combined_csv.csv", index=False, encoding='utf-8-sig')
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Did you check if the path is correct?

Comment: can you try doing `cd /Users/RW/Desktop/London_Crime_Data` and let know what happens ?

Comment: Path is correct, copied it directly. I tried adding cd - got the same response.

Comment: It's a folder containing a few CSVs that need to be combined, they have the exact same format (headers, etc.).  Does anyone know a better way to combine them without duplicating the headers?

Comment: did you try adding double back slashes to the file path?

Answer (score 1):

If the path is meant to be relative (starting in current directory and ascending into it), you should try removing the leading '/'. 
If the path is absolute and you are on Windows, you might want to add the drive letter. That are the options I can think of.

Comment: Using Mac, tried removing the initial '/' still no luck

Comment: Ok, but you can cd into the directory on your terminal?

Comment: Also, get the same response on the terminal - says 'No such file or directory'.

Comment: If the terminal cannot find it as well, it seems like the folder is not in that path...

Comment: Sorry my bad, it is there. I moved the folder to downloads to see if that would help. Ran the path again in terminal after moving it back and it responded with "is a directory".

Comment: And the program still does not find it? Then there is one last thing I could imagine. Maybe on mac, the path has to be terminated by '/'. So `csv_filepath = '/Users/RW/Desktop/London_Crime_Data/'`

Comment: Still no luck, I am using Google Collaboratory if that makes a difference.

Comment: I guess that is the issue then. Google Collaboratory can not access your local files directly. You first have to upload them on the left side under files.

Comment: Sorted, switched to Jupyter and it worked! Thanks for the help and patience.

Comment: Cool. Glad it works now :) You are very welcome. Have a nice day :)